# Fetch user email with C# Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, email, sdk

I would like to fetch a user's email using the C# Facebook SDK. How can I do so? I've tried the code below, but I just get an empty email. Is it because I somehow need to ask for more rights? If so, how do I do that?

```
Facebook.FacebookClient fbc = new Facebook.FacebookClient(user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
dynamic clientCredentials = await fbc.GetTaskAsync("oauth/access_token", 
    new{client_id = facebookClientId,client_secret = facebookClientSecret,
    grant_type = "client_credentials",redirect_uri = "https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/signin-facebook"});

fbc.AccessToken = clientCredentials.access_token;
fbc.AppId = facebookClientId;
fbc.AppSecret = facebookClientSecret;
string id = user.UserId.Replace("Facebook:", string.Empty);
dynamic result = await fbc.GetTaskAsync(id + "?fields=id,name,picture,last_name,first_name,gender");
```

Best regards
TJ78

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather the `email` permission in the login Url's scope parameter, otherwise you will not be able to receive the `email` field.